# Как добавить переменную RANK каждому узлу бинарного дерева?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

Как добавить переменную RANK каждому узлу бинарного дерева?

**RANK** - поле, которое указывает относительное положение узла в его поддереве, а именно - **1 + количество узлов в левом поддереве.**

Ниже представлен код генерации бинарного дерева:

```
    class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):

        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data

# Insert method to create nodes
    def insert(self, data):

        if self.data:
            if data < self.data:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(data)
            elif data > self.data:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.right.insert(data)
        else:
            self.data = data

    def findval(self, lkpval):
        if lkpval < self.data:
            if self.left is None:
                return str(lkpval)+" Not Found"
            return self.left.findval(lkpval)
        elif lkpval > self.data:
            if self.right is None:
                return str(lkpval)+" Not Found"
            return self.right.findval(lkpval)
        else:
            print(str(self.data) + ' is found')
# Print the tree
    def PrintTree(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.PrintTree()
        print( self.data),
        if self.right:
            self.right.PrintTree()


root = Node(12)
root.insert(6)
root.insert(14)
root.insert(3)
root.PrintTree()
```

Answer (score 2):

Выполните центрированный обход (как в PrintTree), записывая `self.rank = getrank(left) + 1` и возвращая значение `return self.rank + getrank(right)`